# Broken Magento 2 Admin Design

Tags: admin, magento-2.1, adminhtml, css

Current version is Magento 2.1.3. Installed from dist. Many admin pages are looking broken like this.

[image: Problem with the admin design]

Although CSS seems to be loaded like following:

[image: Css loaded on admin]

I tried clearing/flushing cache, deleting pub/static contents and rebuilding them and compiled less/sass again. Nothing helped so far.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I had the same problem, but unfortunately, the following solution didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to developer mode and then deploying theme source solved the above issue.

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy --area=adminhtml --theme=Magento/backend css/styles-old css/styles
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```