# Magento 2 backend - tables en layout not fully loaded

Tags: magento2, backend

On a Magento 2.1.5 installation our backend layout is suddenly very odd. 
Tables are not complete, the navigation bar scrolls over content and some other CSS/JS related issues. Updated to 2.1.5, but didn't fix the issues. Upgrade and compile commands ran several times, as well as emptying caches. Present in all browsers.

[image: see this attachment]

Anyone experienced the same issues?

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm that this post fixes the issue (in my case):
[Broken Magento 2 Admin Design](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154305/broken-magento-2-admin-design)

Switching to developer mode and then deploying theme source solved the above issue.

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy --area=adminhtml --theme=Magento/backend css/styles-old css/styles
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```